# Alternative to Digital Servo?

Tags: dc-motor, servo

I recently picked up a high torque digital servo for a project I'm working on, where the servo needs to lift a bar about an inch, and hold it there, and then set it back down.  The issue is that the digital servo, with any weight applied to it, will sing while holding the weight, or even when it's sitting; because it's constantly looking for center.  Could anyone recommend an alternative motor type to digital which will be silent when not moving?

I tried disengaging the digital motor (by stopping a signal to it), but it would continue to try and center on the last transmission, instead of freefloat.

For anyone wondering, I was using the [Hitec 37954S HS-7954SH](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027L7UDA)

Comment: Have you considered a high torque stepper motor instead? There is no motor movement or singing when no stepping impulses are applied.

Comment: There are no digital servos. There are analog servos with digital control interfaces.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - Stepper motors have crap holding (and dynamic) torque. Frankly, stepper motors are just crap in about every way, except driver simplicity.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Worth looking up the detent torque / cogging torque rating of stepper motors. Yes, the cheap hobby steppers with soft iron cores do not have much detent torque. Those aren't the only type of stepper motors, incidentally. "*[holding torques up to 1845 oz-in](http://www.omega.com/pptst/OMHT_Series.html)*".

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - Yeah, there are 1845 oz-in stepper motors. The motor on the page you link, incidentally, happens to weigh **12 pounds**! You could get that same torque from a <5 lb servo motor.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I'm not sure why this is being discussed: Did the OP say how much torque is needed? No. Did they specify a motor weight? No. Did they specify a budget? No. Did you know that rare-earth-magnet steppers outperform servos in hold torque per motor weight? No. Is there any point taking this even further out of your knowledge area? No.

Comment: As you say, the servo is hunting and, without a load to dampen the servo response, you'd have to exert control over the servo loop. I couldn't find a data sheet or technical manual for it on the Hitec website. Is there any kind of standby input or suchlike that you can make use of?

Comment: Hitec makes geared servos with internal drivers for radio control applications and things derived from that, they aren't intended to be inactivated.  Probably the poster's application would be better addressed by something backdrive resistant, like a jack screw, but that is beyond the scope of this particular site.  As for the comment about steppers outperforming servos in holding torque, that could perhaps be true for direct drive motors, but those are neither what is being contemplated here, nor what would be an appropriate choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve the problem. But most servos will "sing" when you apply a load to maintain the position, analog or digital. Here's a few ideas:

1. Use a second servo or a solenoid to apply a brake or locking mechanism. Pull the load up, apply the lock, then cut the power to the main servo. To lower the load, apply power to main servo, release the brake and lower the load servo.
2. Consider using an analog servo instead of cutting the power to a digital servo. By using an analog servo, you can simply stop sending the timing pulses and it will stop "hunting". This is more elegant than cutting power to a digital servo. However, no pulses means no power to the motor so you will still need a brake or lock otherwise your raised load will lower itself from gravity.
3. Use a sail winch servo. These have much higher gear ratios, do multiple rotations, and run slower. For example [this 3.5 turn Hitech analog servo](http://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/boat-servos/hs-785hb-3.5-turn-winch-servo/product). By having a high gear ratio, the torque on the motor from lifting your load is small and not **as likely** to "sing". You will need to experiment to be sure because they don't publish very good specs for hobby servos. Again, you can stop sending the timing pulses to stop it from "singing", but it also stops power to the motor.
4. Use a DC motor with a gearbox and/or screw-drive mechanism and limit switches. One switch tells you you've hit the top limit, the other the bottom limit. You'll need a bridge using transistors or relays so you can reverse your DC motor rotation. Then you simply drive the DC motor forward until you hit the top limit switch. Or reverse the motor until you hit the bottom limit switch. Again, you can use high gear ratios or a screw-drive so that the motor cannot be moved by the load, or you can use a solenoid or servo brake/lock if you need lower gear ratios for speed. This type of mechanism is popular in American homes in the form of a garage door opener :)
5. Folks mentioned stepper motors, but those are usually big for the torque you might need, but might work for your application. They still need a switch or some way to calibrate the position (e.g. bang it to a stop).